# Matching pairs in excel

Tags: excel

Every week, I randomly pair together two users for a peer review. Sometimes users have the week off. Each user is assigned an ID # to make the pairing chart simple.

```
ID #      Name      Week 1 Pair     Week 2 Pair      Week n Pair...
1         Bob       2               3
2         Doug      1               -
3         Brian     4               1
4         Joe       3               -
5         Mary      6               7
6         Jane      5               10   
7         Ron       10              5
8         Mark      -               -
9         Steve     -               -
10        Anna      7               6
```

I want to take this pairing chart and send out a weekly reminder email with the pairing. Emails should look like this.

Example 1:

```
Week 1 Pairings:
Bob 
Doug
Brian
Joe
Mary 
Jane
Ron
Anna
```

Example 2:

```
Week 2 Pairings:
Bob
Brian
Mary
Ron
Jane
Anna
```

Just each pair in one column, one after the other, no separators. I do the grouping with formatting. There should be no duplicates (for example, in Week 1 - Bob (1) is paired with Doug (2), but Doug (2) is also paired with Bob (1). Only one of these pairs should appear in the weekly reminder email).

How can I use Excel to get this information based on the original pairing chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Data looks like this]

```
F2=IFERROR(INDIRECT("B"&MOD(SMALL(IF(C$2:C$11="-","X",IF(C$2:C$11<$A$2:$A$11,C$2:C$11,$A$2:$A$11)*1000+ROW($B$2:$B$11)),ROW(A1)),1000)),"")
```

It is an array formula, click ctrl+shift+enter to complete.